# Which statistical techniques can be used to decide which definition of sets produces the most coherent grouping of data

Tags: clustering, terminology, methodology, binning, timeseries-segmentation

To explain. I am a historian, and an almost complete statistical novice.

I am interested in exploring the ways in which generational
alignments might be identified, not via use of generational labels, but by patterns of coalescence and division on the basis of age/birth date, how one would describe this in statistical or mathematical terminology, and how data sets could be interrogated to ascertain what given boundary points (years of birth) create the greatest degree of coherence, or concentration.
To given an example. I posit that people who contribute to multi-author books will not be randomly distributed, but will tend to share a generational identity. If I have a data set which has a substantial (say 1000) number of books with 5 or more contributors identified by birth date, would it be possible to analyse this data to identify which groups of 15-year birth date ranges ('generations') create the greatest degree of 'coalescence' or concentration, as defined by the highest mean proportion across the entire set of contributors from a single generational group? And what is the appropriate terminology for this sort of analysis (concentration, coalescence, something else?).

I could offer variant data sets which would include groups (eg members of a society) of varying sizes, the birthdates of all members being known, from which I would like to be able to deduce which birth-date ranges produce the 'best fit' in terms of fewest members from outside the predominant 15 year birth date cohort.
I realise there are some technical issues relating to questions of the breadth of the cluster, but at the least would like guidance towards what branch of statistical analysis I am dealing with here (binning? segmentation? clustering? discretization?; what sort of techniques should I be looking at (k-means? clustering algorithms? gaussian analysis?); how would this process of defining 'best fit' or greatest coherence be described in mathematical language?

Comment: I don't follow this.  Are you trying to find the book whose authors' birth dates are most similar?

Comment: No, my interest is the patterns of the whole population; how far are groupings like the authors of a multi-author book, etc, clustered generationally (ie by age).  It would be relatively easy to measure this by defining a priori a set of age cohorts, but I'm particularly interested in how one might analyse such data sets so as to determine which cohort definitions would produce the greatest degree of clustering. I realise there are various technical problems to overcome, but at this stage am just not sure what terminologies and methods I should be looking to. If you can help...

Comment: Maybe better to analyze without binning into age groups? Look into measures of [tag:diversity] maybe. Clustering is based on a similarity measure, you can get similarities from diversities. Or maybe some form of multidimensional scaling?

Comment: Is everybody involved already dead? That is, are there people born in, say, in 2000, who have not completed academic career?

Comment: This is historical data, so everyone involved is dead. But I don't think that would have any implications for the sort of analysis I have in mind, which I would have thought would work just as well to test the generational solidarities of contemporary generations, say generation x vs generation y.

Comment: Kjetil, thanks, but  I'm afraid this is where my lack of statistical knowledge might be a barrier but my response would be (i) I am interested in age effects, and in particular clustering age effects, so how far I can identify clusters is my key research question. (ii) as far as I can see, diversity approaches require pre-defined categorisations, but I am hoping for a technique that will identify or refine the categorisation based on the single dimension of age/birth date. Any further thoughts?